# System.Threading.Timer trying to make timer for same time every day

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am using System.Threading.Timer in a console service app, and trying to make timer for same time every day.

Initially I am good if I start the app prior to the time.  Like if my time is 10:05 and I start the app at 10:00 we are good. But if I start at 10:06 I dont know how to tell the timespan to go 24 hours ahead.

Thanks for any help!

```
public void SetUpTimer(TimeSpan alertTime)
{
    DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan timeToGo = alertTime - current.TimeOfDay;

    if (timeToGo < TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("MyApp", "Timer Passed  " );

        return;//time already passed
    }

    timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x =>
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("MhyApp", "Timer Set  " + timeToGo);

        this.MethodRunsAt();
    },  null, timeToGo, System.Threading.Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use cron expressions to solve this task. For example you can use Quartz.Net library (it is available through nuget).

Your cron expression will look like this:

```
0 10 * * *    //“At 10:00”
```

It tells that action will be performed exactly “At 10:00” every day. Or if you want you can even start it every monday and wednesday:

```
0 10 * * 1,3  //“At 10:00 on Monday and Wednesday.”
```

Or if you want to make it periodic in some time scope:

```
0/2 10 * * 1,3  //“At every 2nd minute from 0 through 59 past hour 10 on Monday and Wednesday.”
```

Comment: This sounds like a great package but I cant even compile the examples. I messed with it for a while but put it aside for now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
public void SetUpTimer(TimeSpan alertTime)
{
    DateTime targetDateTime = DateTime.Today.Add(alertTime);
    if (targetDateTime < DateTime.Now)
    {
        targetDateTime = targetDateTime.AddDays(1);
    }
    TimeSpan timeToGo = targetDateTime - DateTime.Now;
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x =>
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("MhyApp", "Timer Set  " + timeToGo);

        this.MethodRunsAt();
    }, null, timeToGo, System.Threading.Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
}
```

Comment: This is close. I wasnt able to use it exactly as you can't have Timespan = DateTime.  I wrote a little extra code and let it running to make sure it fires off the next 24 hours. If I works I will post the final. Thank you for the help

Comment: _you can't have Timespan = DateTime_  Not sure what you mean by that...would probably need to see more of your code.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: TimeSpan timeToGo = targetDateTime - DateTime.Now; Cant do that. But I have it worked out and waiting to see if it triggers tomorrow properly.  Thanks again

Comment: You can replace that with `TimeSpan timeToGo = targetDateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);`.